# First two rows per combination of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Given a table like this in PostgreSQL:

`Messages`

```
message_id | creating_user_id | receiving_user_id | created_utc
-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------
 1         | 1                | 2                 | 1424816011
 2         | 3                | 2                 | 1424816012
 3         | 3                | 2                 | 1424816013
 4         | 1                | 3                 | 1424816014
 5         | 1                | 3                 | 1424816015
 6         | 2                | 1                 | 1424816016
 7         | 2                | 1                 | 1424816017
 8         | 1                | 2                 | 1424816018
```

I want to get the newest two rows per `creating_user_id`/`receiving_user_id` where the other user_id is 1. So the result of the query should look like:

```
message_id | creating_user_id | receiving_user_id | created_utc
-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------
 1         | 1                | 2                 | 1424816011
 4         | 1                | 3                 | 1424816014
 5         | 1                | 3                 | 1424816015
 6         | 2                | 1                 | 1424816016
```

Using a window function with `row_number()` I can get the first 2 messages for each `creating_user_id` or the first 2 messages for each `receiving_user_id`, but I'm not sure how to get the first two messages for per `creating_user_id`/`receiving_user_id`.

Comment: You could use your window function with `row_number()` in two separate queries and combine results with a `UNION ALL`

Comment: @JNevill I was thinking that, but if user_1 sends user_2 2 messages, one query would result in 1 row, the other in 0 rows, which is not what am I looking for. Or am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: I think you would be fine. The first query would be something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY creating_user_id ORDER BY created_utc DESC) as daterank ... WHERE creating_user_id = 1 ... having daterank <=2` And the second would be similar, just using the `receiving_user_id` Both queries should return different results unless it's possible that `creating_user_id` can send messages to `receiving_user_id`

Comment: I took the liberty to rewrite the title, I think this is closer to what the question is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you filter rows where one of both columns is `1` (and irrelevant), and `1` happens to be the smallest number of all, you can simply use `GREATEST(creating_user_id, receiving_user_id)` to distill the *relevant* number to `PARTITION BY`. (Else you could employ `CASE`.)

The rest is standard procedure: calculate a row number in a subquery and select the first two in the outer query:

```
SELECT message_id, creating_user_id, receiving_user_id, created_utc
FROM (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY GREATEST (creating_user_id
                                                  , receiving_user_id)
                             ORDER BY created_utc) AS rn
   FROM   messages
   WHERE  1 IN (creating_user_id, receiving_user_id)
   ) sub
WHERE  rn < 3
ORDER  BY created_utc;
```

Exactly your result.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ab692/1)